# Click next page using mechanize ruby

Tags: ruby, click, hyperlink, mechanize

I'm a new in mechanize (using in ruby) i have a web page like that http://goo.gl/H4x54 . I want to use mechanize to click Next page > but i can't find link in source page . How can i do

Comment: How can't you find a link in a page that you created?

Comment: I can't find next page's link to click. In souce page : <a onclick="self.scrollTo(0,110);" id="ctl00_ContentMain_lbtnFooterNext" class="paging" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentMain$lbtnFooterNext','')" style="float:right">Next page &gt;</a>
I'm a starter in mechanize and ruby so i don't know how to do

Comment: possible duplicate of [Click to next page using mechanize?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17671634/click-to-next-page-using-mechanize)