# Click to next page using mechanize?

Tags: ruby, click, mechanize

I want to using mechanize to click next page in [this link](http://goo.gl/H4x54).

I see that this code:

```
<pre>
    <a onclick="self.scrollTo(0,110);" id="ctl00_ContentMain_lbtnFooterNext" class="paging" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentMain$lbtnFooterNext','')" style="float:right">Next page &gt;</a>
</pre>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: There's not enough info to answer your question. Do you use mechanize to proxy that page and return response 'as is'? If so then you should be able to click that link from UI after you render it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. The `Next Page` link on that page is a JavaScript action, and `Mechanize` doesn't understand JavaScript.

See also [Clicking link with JavaScript in Mechanize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10239379)